# how to view the commits and the commit times for just one branch

Tags: git

I have a lot of branches and I'm not sure wtch one contains the features I need. What I need is a way to see the commits for  a particular branch, for example I want to see all of the commits and the commit time on master, or all of the commits whit the time on staging, but just for one branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can do that using git-log along with the branch you need, like this:

```
git log BRANCH
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have too many branches, you should do something about it. Discard the ones you don't know what they were already, merge those with finished features, plan completing the unfinished ones, rename them so you know what is what etc.
2. `git log` shows only commits reachable from the arguments, so if you say `git log master`, you'll only see commits that are part of `master`. Similarly `git log` will only show you commits reachable from currently checked out branch.
3. Git commits are not on a branch. They simply form a tree and branches point to some commits in that tree. Commit is reachable from a branch if it's the commit the branch points to or it's ancestor. But I suspect that's what you actually want.